# Regex - Match multi-line content between double curly brackets

Tags: regex, phpstorm

I am am trying to refactor some code and need to use regular expression to find a large number of strings. An example string is like:

```
  {{ Form::text('twitter', Input::old('twitter'), 
              array(
                    'class'=>'form-control ',
                    'placeholder'=>'E.g http://www.twitter.com/MyTwitterPage'
                    ))

 }}
```

I have managed to use `\{\{(.*\s*Form::.*\s*)\}\}` to match strings when they're on a single line, but it fails to match multi-line strings such as the above.

Also, I'm using PHPStorm's regex find feature if that's of any help.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try [`\{\{(\s*Form::\w*\([\s\S]*?)}}`](https://regex101.com/r/sI9sJ8/1).

Comment: Or a more effecient one: [`\{\{(\s*Form::\w*\((?:[^}]*(?:}[^}]+)*))}}`](https://regex101.com/r/sI9sJ8/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\{\{(\s*Form::\w*\((?:[^}]*(?:}[^}]+)*))}}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sI9sJ8/2)

It is basically the same as `\{\{(\s*Form::\w*\([\s\S]*?)}}`, but it uses an unrolled logic and is thus much effecient.

Answer (score 0):

Preparse the file and remove newlines.

or set the /s flag to the regex and see if that works, not sure if php supports it.

`/\{\{(.*\s*Form::.*\s*)\}\}/s`